# SUM of a values in a column in MySQL and group them

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I need to design a leader board for a quiz website that I am making. I store the user scores in a database table called 'user_record' which has the following structure:

```
'user_id'  - varchar(254) -which holds the user id for a particular score
'score'  - int(2) -which holds the score
'time'  - timesatamp -which has the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
'date'  - date -which has the CURDATE()
```

Now I need to sum the values for each user_id for the current date and display the top 5 in a descending order. 
I have the following code for this, however it doesn't seem to be working. Any help?

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include "connection.php";
    $w=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,SUM(Score) from score WHERE date=CURDATE() GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC limit 5");
    $b=$row=mysql_fetch_array($w);
    while($b)
    {
    $user_id=$row['user_id'];
    $score=$row['score'];
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user_id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $score; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: You mentioned that Your table name is 'user_record' while You're selecting from 'score' which might be most important issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
  $w=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,SUM(Score) from score WHERE date=CURDATE() GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC limit 5"); 
  $b=$row=mysql_fetch_array($w);
  while($b)
```

by

```
 $w=mysql_query("SELECT user_id,SUM(Score) as score from user_record WHERE date=CURDATE() GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC limit 5");
  while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($w) )
```

Comment: Done that.. I still get the error **Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

Comment: @user2801699 fix your query like that `from user_record`

Comment: @user2801699 edited my answer take a look

Comment: Got it, and the query worked too.. but the result was not as intended.. I just got one entry on the user_id field and nothing under the score

Comment: try again now my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

the right query is

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(score) from user_record WHERE date=CURDATE() GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC limit 5
```